# awscli python version shows 2.7 instead of 3.6 on windows 7

Tags: aws-cli

I installed awscli with msi installer on windows 7.
I have python 3.6 installed on my machine, but after installing the awscli msi I ran

```
aws --version
```

command on both git bash and command prompt it is showing

```
aws-cli/1.15.3 Python/2.7.9 Windows/7 botocore/1.10.3 

Python/2.7.9
```

I used

```
pip installed --user --upgrade
```

already but it is still shoing the Python/2.7.9 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html clearly states that the MSI installer comes with python bundled. If you want to use your preinstalled Python, you should use pip to install, as recommended by the developers.

Comment: thanks. I reinstalled through pip and it's working now

Comment: Then you could mark my answer as solving your problem ;)